# Mounting a TV on a chimney breast

Tags: mounting, chimney, television

In our new house the master bedroom is on the upper level and has a chimney running through the room from the living room below. It's painted brick and all 4 sides are exposed (you can walk around it). We thought it might be a good idea to mount a tv on it so we can see it from our bed.

We haven't committed to anything yet. It will likely be a smaller TV especially since, unfortunately, it's the narrow side of the chimney that faces us. The fireplace in the living room is bricked up and simply decorative now, but I believe the water heater and the furnace may still be vented into this chimney. The house was build in the 1920's and I assume the chimney has always been there.

What would be a good way to mount a TV in such a situation? I'm a little leery of drilling into the chimney and was wonder if there is something that would wrap around it to support the TV. We will run cables down from the ceiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

1/4 diameter, 1.5 to 2 inch long (depending on bracket thickness) [Tapcons](http://www.tapcon.com/products). This is not an ad, it's what I've been using for 20+ years. They will not penetrate the inside of the chimney. Its painted so holes in the brick are a non-cosmetic issue. A wrap-a-round metal band would look like it's from the 80's and not *anywhere* near as strong. You can have as large of a TV as you want if your willing to drill some extra holes in the mounting bracket and "tapcon the hell out of it".

Comment: When installing Tapcons it is important to not over-torque the fastener. This is especially true for soft brick or masonry materials and when fasteners have the hex style driver heads. In my experience past a certain point the Tapcon can strip out and leave you with a fastener that does not stay tight.

Comment: Indeed, I've snapped off my share of heads. 3/16th are garbage. I find 1/4" don't strip nearly as easily. Also important to line up your holes with brick, not mortar.

Comment: All true. It may be good advice for a new user of Tapcons to watch one of numerous web videos that show how it is typical to pulse trigger the driver to screw in the fastener in steps and then stop just at the instant the head snugs tight against the surface of the item being fastened.

Comment: Putting them in with an impact driver is fantastic. Stop half a second after it starts to sound funny. @MichaelKaras