# Can I use a toggle bolt if there's no space behind the drywall?

Tags: drywall, concrete, installation, drill, anchor

While trying to install a 14lb metal shelf to the wall, I had learned from a previous installation mishap to upgrade from plastic anchors to something stronger. I picked up a few toggle bots (3/16" w 3" bolts).

When I started drilling the 1/2" hole, I realized my bit wouldn't go much further than an inch in. It was a hard stop. After the 1" of drywall immediately behind it is what looks like concrete. There is **NO** space between the drywall and the concrete.

I live in a new condo and the wall happens to be one that I share with my neighbour. I'm not sure what material it's made of, or if these toggle bolts will work.

Does anyone have any advise on how I can get these heavy shelf installed, toggle or no toggle.

Answer (score 1):

I don't suppose you have a hammer drill? [Tapcons](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/48913/mounting-a-tv-on-a-chimney-breast/48924#48924)! (my favorite concrete screws, you need 2", maybe 2.25") bushed out with 1" worth of washers. Make sure they're not home first ;) If you fall into a void after drilling into the 'concrete' they're probably cinder-blocks. If you then can't get the screws to bite, make the hole even bigger and use really long toggle bolts. If this is the case be prepared for having to do it both ways as some holes will be into the meat of the block and others into the voids.