# What masonry anchor should I use to install both window boxes and shutters into brick?

Tags: masonry, anchor, shutters

I have a brick house and my wife and I want to install plastic shutters and wooden window boxes on some windows. I know that the shutters will not be heavy load bearers, but the windows boxes will be much heavier.

I've looked all over online and am still pretty confused by the differences in the masonry anchors that I might need to use for this project.

**I see tapcon screws are anchors and screws in one, but would they be strong enough to handle a window box?**

**Are there standard plastic/metal anchors I could use that would work just like a drywall anchors?**

Comment: Do you own a hammer drill?

Comment: I do not, I've been told that a regular drill will work, but take longer.

Comment: Depending on how hard the masonry is (common brick is soft, glazed will be more difficult), it might just laugh at you. Also, you may need a whole pack of drill bits. Tapconing into a mortar joint is to be avoided.

Comment: Any reason you say tapcon shouldn't used on a mortar joint?

Comment: It's real easy to ream the hole to large while drilling into mortar; pullout strength will be degraded either way. However, without a hammer drill, that's probably where there going to have to go. Some planter boxes? Sure. Your 60" TV? No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

[Tapcons](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/48913/mounting-a-tv-on-a-chimney-breast) <(Stack Exchange discussion) will do the trick. Just use enough of the right ones and some washers. Do not use plastic anything. Personally, they're my favorite and I dread making the holes for these, [wedge anchors](http://www.tennholdings.com/products/pkwedge.php), when I need something to be structural.

[image]

---

Recently I've begun using these, [Wedge Bolts](http://www.powers.com/product_07246.php) instead, where something better than a Tapcon is necessary: (**all fasteners shown require a hammer-drill** and a masonry bit to drill the hole, and I highly recommend using an impact gun to drive them)

[image]