# Can I hang shelves on a brick wall from the mortar, not the brick?

Tags: drill, brick, mortar, rental, shelves

We're renting a house with exposed brick walls inside, and would like to put up some shelves. The landlord doesn't want us drilling into the brick itself, but he's fine with us drilling into the mortar. If we mount shelves this way, will the mortar be strong enough to hold them up?

Comment: Depends on the shelf geometry, fasteners, and mortar.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @popham and the load!

Comment: Ask for forgiveness not permission. Move in fees are non-refundable anyway. The dick move would be taking your shelves when you move out. You're making improvements to the house, go nuts. "Some planter boxes? Sure. Your 60" TV? No." Tapcons don't list spec for mortar. https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/51888/what-masonry-anchor-should-i-use-to-install-both-window-boxes-and-shutters-into

Comment: Or [Why did concrete screws feel loose when installed in a brick wall?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/132649/why-did-concrete-screws-feel-loose-when-installed-in-a-brick-wall)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are placing a lot of weight on the shelves mounting in the mortar would be prefered. Be sure you use the appropriate anchors. The directions will give you information on the size, number etc for the amount of weight you want to support. This link may help: https://www.wikihow.com/Hang-Something-on-Brick

Comment: This question is [a dupe](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/132651/23295) among numerous offerings, you linked off-site, and -1 : ITW, the makers of Tapcons, *do not* 'prefer' they go into mortar. If you said *I'd* prefer them in mortar, then I can't disagree out loud.