# How to anchor railings into concrete correctly

Tags: concrete, anchor, railing

Where I live the most popular way to anchor railings or fence into concrete is a method that I cannot find any reference about it on the web.
A 7mm hole is drilled into concrete and then a 8mm steel rebar without any coating is inserted into the hole with a hammer. Then the railing is welded on site with the rebar.This always works no failures.

The other less common way that is not preferred due to being hard to do and more expensive is with bolts with a flange.

Which way should I prefer for anchoring a long railing?

Comment: I'm confused about two things here. First, how does an 8mm rod fit a 7mm hole? Then, how is an 8mm rod adequate to support a railing? Even if it's high-grade steel that's quite small. Please revise your post to explain in detail what you're trying to do.

Comment: You use a hammer and so it fits tightly. I dont know how it is but most railings/fences here in greece are installed this way and have no issues or it seems so. It is very hard to find someone in the trade who uses bolts you have to ask for it and it gets lot more expensive. Here is an example from my home with 2m tall railing https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_hvXa-gVdItqQW1tSBIqaHDGslaS0AtN/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Which way you should prefer is totally up to you. The rebar into a hole is very unfamiliar to Americans, but seems to be common place in Greece, while it's exactly opposite in Greece, so it seems. Both methods (apparently) work well, so this is totally opinion based - your opinion, not ours, therefore this is off-topic for here.

Comment: Use the giant wedge bolts at the bottom of this answer [What masonry anchor should I use to install both window boxes and shutters into brick?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/51888/what-masonry-anchor-should-i-use-to-install-both-window-boxes-and-shutters-into)

Comment: @FreeMan This question is open to evidence based approaches. There is evidence that multiple approaches work.  Having two approaches that are supported by evidence does  *not* make this an opinion based question.

Answer (score 1):

There are several anchoring system for attaching to concrete or brick masonry. My favorite is a screw type anchor called tapcons. You need a hammer drill and a normal drill or impact driver to sink the concrete screws. The dill bit is included in the box of screws usually. Drill and prime the hole to remove excess dust. Then sink the screws directly in the holes. It cuts the grooves into the concrete when sinking.

There are also drop in anchors, redhead brand... with the hammer drill make your hole the correct dia. for the drop in anchor. Drill deep enough so the top is just below the surface. Then you have a drive tool that will flare the anchor securely in the hole. Afterwards the anchor will accept a normal threaded screw of the proper size. Remember to use weather resistant outdoor screws.

For widow shutters drill 1/4 in holes into morter joints an use plastic insert anchors. Then attach threaded screws thru the shutter into the plastic anchor

Comment: You have a web connection, search for concrete fasteners on a builders supply. You can ask a salesman his idea. Remember you need the proper tools to drill holes in concrete. You can on the cheap, drill a 1/4 " hole and attach wood by driving two 16 penny nails thru yr wood or other material into the 1/4 in hole. The nails will compress and hold  in the holes. Securing the material to be attached

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you're from but the only time I've seen your popular way of doing it is when the railing rusted out and needed a repair. If a flange isn't available, get some 38mm angle iron and cut it to the width of the railing. Drill holes in both sides. Bolt two pieces on each railing post and lag shield and lag screw each piece to the concrete. Depending on the length and height, you might need four pieces on each post.