# Can I reuse anchor bolt sleeves?

Tags: installation, mounting, bolts, fastener

A bracket for mounting a TV was attached to my brick fireplace by the previous home owner.  All that remains now are four little metal tubes, which I think are leftover parts of some kind of anchor bolts.  There are no threads in these tubes.

[image: metal tubes from anchors]

I would like to reuse the existing holes to mount my TV.  Is there a fastener that would be compatible with and safe to use in these tubes?  Should I try to remove the tubes, or am I better off drilling new holes?

Comment: Are you sure there are no threads at all?  What is the inside diameter of the hole?

Comment: The inside diameter is 5/16ths of an inch.  There are no threads inside, and I don't see a taper nut at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you have are similar to these, *sleeve and taper nut anchor bolts*:

[image]

<sub>[source](http://www.fastenerindia.in/taper_nut.html)</sub>

If you're real lucky, the nuts are still properly positioned and you can screw bolts back into them. I wouldn't bother though, my preferred masonry screws are Tapcons. I thought this question was going to be about lead wedge anchors, which if not totally deformed, you *could* use again. These I wouldn't reuse even if I got 'lucky'. Tap the sleeves in with a hammer or grind them off if they don't budge (you don't want to crack the wall).

If you don't have a grinder, you could fold the sleeve in on itself using a hammer and a flat head, working your way around in a circle.

You *might* be able to remove the sleeves with alligator tipped 'locking pliers' (aka, needle nosed vise grips) and a hammer, to reuse the holes for the same type of fasteners. Make sure you get all the parts of the old fastener out.

**Remove or sink those sleeves. [Use Tapcons](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/48913/mounting-a-tv-on-a-chimney-breast).**

Comment: So, i can only reuse sleeve and taper nut bolt sleeves if the nut is still in the sleeve?  No fasteners are designed to slide inside the old sleeve?

Comment: @j.wittwer - None that I know of. I wouldn't count on an old sleeve holding another fastener inside it (which might work but that's not how they were designed and there's really no way to know for sure how well it will hold if you do).

Comment: I was able to pull the old sleeves out with needle nose pliers.  Then I was able to use a pick to pull out the old nuts.  If I had the bolts from the original installation, I probably could have reused the old sleeves - since without the nut pulled into them they had retracted to their original radius.